# Where can I get Google Apps (gapps) for Xperia Mini STi15 ("smultron")?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rooting, google-apps

I am want gapps for `cyanogenmod9`

goo.im is no longer accessible and everyone seem to still share the same link.
Please share the updated link to me.

Just so you know when I say not "accessible" what I really mean is that the site contains only the following text --

> Hello,
>
> Unfortunately, as of this time, the main portions of goo.im have been
>   disabled. Due to a finance issue, our CDN account has been suspended,
>   and all files stored on it are effectively non-accessible. Due to some
>   RL issues on my(Alexander)'s part, once goo started actively losing
>   money 6 months ago, I had changed jobs a bit to help support goo.
>   Unfortunately, this wasn't enough combined with some other issues that
>   crept up on me. Due to this, I'm formally shutting down Goo. There is
>   an offer in to take over the files and hosting from a generous
>   sponsor, however, until the financial issues are sorted out, they are
>   unable to adsorb Goo. It's been my pleasure to serve files for you all
>   for the past couple of years, and I wish everyone good luck into the
>   future.
>
> -- Snipa/Alexander Blair
>
> If you have picked up a sponor account within the last two months,
>   please reach out to us if you'd like a refund. It may take some time,
>   but we'll do our best to get these processed and sent out. -- Thanks
>   for everyone who's supported us over the years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://basketbuild.com/gapps) you can download Google Apps